# Reverse for 'profile_view' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['in/(?P<username>[^/]+)/$']

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

views.py :

```py
User = get_user_model()

class ProfileView(View):
  def get(self, request, *args ,**kwargs):
       username = kwargs.get('username')
       try:
          user = User.objects.get(username=username)
       except Exception as e:
          return HttpResponse('<h1>This page does not exist. </h1>')

       if username == request.user.username:
       
        context = { 'user': user }
       
        return render (request, 'authprofile.html' , context=context)
        
       else:
         context = { 'user': user }
         return render (request, 'authprofile.html' , context=context)##
```

---

urls.py :

```py
from user.views import ProfileView
urlpatterns = [
     path('in/<str:username>/',login_required(ProfileView.as_view()),name='profile_view'),
```

Comment: In the `else` branch, what is the value of `user`? You might try using `print(user)` to determine.

Comment: You have `if username == request.user.username:` but then execute identical code with both outcomes. Can you try telling us what you're trying to do?   About the error you're getting it seems that you're opening the url without providing the <username> parameter. Can you share with us the url the you enter in your browser to test this page?